# Can't recognise kanji from image

Tags: translation

[image: Can't recognise kanji]

「おイイ？？？じた炊けてる。」と書いていますが、一つ漢字をなんかよみにくいです。

Answer (score 7, accepted):

「お、イイ感じに炊けてる」ではないですか。Not sure about the meaning, though...

Comment: Suits well... But original writing is just awfull. Thank you a lot!

Comment: The meaning is straightforward enough: "It's turning out well," would be a good translation. Literally it's "It's cooking up well," but that's not how English speakers would put it.

Comment: @botichelli I'd say it's a relatively readable one...

Comment: @Jimmy I see!! For some reason [too much manga?], I feel I understand well the metaphorical meaning of your literal translation! And it feels "cozy". Thanks!